# python sockets and a serial to IP device

Tags: python, sockets

Using a [Lantronix UDS-1100](http://www.lantronix.com/device-networking/external-device-servers/uds1100.html) serial to IP converter.  The goal is to write a small proof of concept piece in Python to capture serial data output by this device over IP.

I've done a couple test projects using sockets in python, but they were all done between python processes (python > python):  listen() on one end, and connect(), sendall() etc on the other.

I *think* I can use sockets for this project, but before I invest a bunch of time into it, wanted to make sure it is a viable solution.

**Can python sockets be used to capture IP traffic when the traffic is originating from a non-python source?**  I have full control over the IP and port that the device sends the serial data to, but there will be no python connect() initiated by the client.  I can pre-pend then serial data with some connect() string if needed.

If sockets won't work, please recommend another solution...guessing it will be REST or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. TCP/IP is supposed to be cross-platform and cross-language, so in theory you should be able to communicate with every kind of device as long as you manage to process and send the expected protocol.

Comment: agree that tcp/ip is cross-platform, but my root question isn't TCP related as much as it's python socket related.  Python sockets listen on TCP ports, and my ser:IP device can send to that TcP port.  However there is no connect() or sendall() happening on the sending end.

Comment: Do you have any anecdotal experience that it will work, or are you just assuming it will work?  I only ask this because I don't want to waste time on an approach that won't work.  Thanks!